# Difference of Android Automotive an Google built-in

Tags: android, built-in, android-auto, android-automotive, automotive

I recently read that Google calls "Android Automotive OS" now "Google built-in".
On some different articles i read that it's still called AAOS and Google built-in is only used for the Google Services(Play Service, Maps etc.) that you can use if you decide to use AAOS as a system.

At first I thought AAOS and Google built-in is the same but now im unsure.

Answer (score 3):

["Google built-in"](https://built-in.google/cars/) is the marketing name for [Google Automotive Services (GAS)](https://developers.google.com/cars#google-automotive-services-gas), which is a licensed product sold to car OEMs consisting of Google Maps, Google Assistant, the Google Play Store, etc.

GAS runs on top of Android Automotive OS (AAOS), which is [an open source operating system](https://source.android.com/docs/devices/automotive/start/what_automotive). If you're familiar with the phone/tablet world, GAS is like [Google Mobile Services (GMS)](https://www.android.com/gms/) while AAOS is like "regular" Android.

See [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Automotive) for more details, including a list of vehicles which run AAOS with/without GAS.

Comment: Comparison with phone/table world makes this answer really easy to understand. Thank you.